# Number of points of discontinuity of $[5x]+\{3x\}$

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

I need to find the number of discontinuous point for

> $$f(x)=[5x]+\{3x\}$$

where [] and {} are the G.I.F and the fractional part functions in the interval [0,5]

My attempt:

I wrote this as $[5x]-[3x]+3x$. Now the $[.]$ function is discontinuous at integer points. So, the points of discontinuity are -

> $0,1/5,2/5,...,25/5$ for the $[5x]$ and
>
> $0,1/3,2/3,...,15/3$ for the $[3x]$.

By inspection, $0,1,2,3,4,5$ belong to both $[5x]$ & $[3x]$ and they are not discontinuous.

But I am still taking some extra points as answer should be $30$ by my book.

Comment: Well, you have $26$ in the first list and $16$ in the second, this adds to $42$.  You've found $6$ points that are not discontinuities, so you need to remove those points from both lists, and $42-12=30$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks... it seems I have forgotten addition and subtraction... I should revise those topics again... ;-(

Comment: As a sidenote,  $x=0$ is not a point of discontinuity anyway because we consider $f$ only on $[0,5]$

Comment: Note that $f(x+1)=f(x)+5$ so you can count the discontinuities in $[0,1)$ and multiply by $5$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen why $0$ would not be a discontinuity ? $f(0)=0$ while $f(0^+)=1^+$.

Comment: $f(\epsilon)=\left\lfloor5\epsilon\right\rfloor+\{3\epsilon\}=3\epsilon$ for small $\epsilon$. @zwim

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Well I interpreted G.I.F as ceil, is it floor ? Not clear to me.

Comment: @zwin Yes, it's 'floor'. I am ancient so I sometimes forget that GIF has been going out of style and being replaced by 'floor.' The confusion is understandable.